# Photogrammetry using blender to Create a Dense Mesh and automatically texture them

Tags: modeling, camera, tracking, photogrammetry

Photogrammetry is the basic requirements when you are working with rocks and other nature assets.

I searched the whole internet in order to find out if there is any tool which can help me in that. To my surprise, there is not a free and open source tool which can do that and support Windows 7 32 bit processors.

So, as we know blender has camera trackers which can be used as markers to create a light mesh (convert markers to vertices). but the problem is that there is no such thing which can help me to create dense mesh cloud and automatically triangulate them in order to be used.

**So, my question is that is there any way to create a dense cloud and can be used to texture the models?**

VisualSFM, Insight3D don't seem to help me with that.

**So, if there's no anyway, so \how much manual work is required for that?**

I want to create a mesh of a human head and few rock and tree pieces.

Comment: There is [meshroom](https://alicevision.github.io). *First entry when searching for: photogrammetry open source*

Comment: @brockmann That doesn't help me because there is no 32-bit version for that. So, I decided to stick to blender

Comment: Suggest install any 64bit linux: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing

Comment: @brockmann I want to stick to 32 bit one because I'm not a professional artist, I don't see it any good to install Linux just for that.

Comment: Performance. Doesn't matter if you are professional or not, it's just faster.

Comment: @brockmann So, there's no any good alternatives for windows 32 bit?

Comment: Why? Performance matters when doing photogrammetry so...

Comment: @brockmann I'm currently not thinking about it. (although I may need performance later)

Comment: Most Linux distributions offer a Live CD/USB option so you do not need to install anything to try it. I even have a Ubuntu USB stick where I installed Ubuntu, so it never touches the hard drive/OS of the machine it is plugged into.

Comment: @rob Won't that damage my harddrive?

Comment: Blender isn't the tool to create point cloud from points on the photos. So provided limitations with 32bit system and free (I suppose that's what you mean by "open source" though free is not necessarily open source and vice versa) - no, I don't think you can find anything useful. 64bit is not only performance but requirement for processing chunks of data photogrammetry app does, it needs quite big amounts of RAM. You'd be better off modelling rocks with some other way

Comment: There is a free workflow (but not with Blender). Gleb Alexandrov made a video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEAbXYDzUjU You use VisualSFM + Meshlab. Personally I bought an Agisoft license, it's an ok price for an one-time payment :)

Answer (score 3):

As others stated on the comments Blender is not the tool to create cloud points from images.

I doubt there is any free, paid or open source photogrammetry tool that works on a 32 bit OS. Photogrammetry would require a more powerful platform, as it  will generate huge amounts of information to create what you call "a dense mesh cloud". A 32bit machine can only deal with 4GB of memory (and that includes the Operating system,that will take at least one GB, leaving you with only 3GB of ram to work with). But even if by some miracle hack you would be able to generate generate objects on such platform, you will hit the limits of the hardware before you can manipulate any of that information.

3D modeling and rendering can be very demanding for any computer, a common mistake folks make is to creating projects that are more ambitious than the resources available to them.

Think of an alternative, more realistic or down to earth way to create what you want within your available means.

Comment: The problem with 32bit OS is not only that it can provide maximum 3GB RAM if everything else swapped, but amount of RAM application can actually use, maximum is around 1,5GB. So from those 3GB even available RAM won't be used (and not every 32bit OS can actually see those 4GB).